# Enable button when picture finishes downloading.

Tags: vb.net, download, progress-bar, sleep

Ok so I have a problem in Visual Basic, I got this code that downloads a picture.

```
WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("picturelinkhere"), "c:\myfile.jpg")
```

After that I have a code that greys out the download button

```
Button1.Enabled = False
```

The thing is that I wanna wait for the file download to finish before I enable `Button1` again.

I have tried to use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

But the problem is that it makes the progressbar in the program very laggy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you downloading the file in a thread other than your main thread?

Comment: What do you mean? I am have added the download file code in a button1, nowhere else.

Comment: Disregard, I didn't notice that you are are calling the Async method of the object.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx):

> To receive notification when the file is available, add an event handler to the DownloadFileCompleted event.

So, for instance, you could do something like this:

```
AddHandler WC.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadFileCompleted
```

And then re-enable the button in the event handler method, like this:

```
Private Sub DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, if anyone else reads this Steven forgot to mention that you need to

    Imports System.ComponentModel

Other than that thanks for the help!!! Now it works perfect! I added the addhandle right below the download code and then the new sub at the bottom before the Class End. Now people will know if they visit this question.